# problem building summarize gem

Tags: ruby, text, rubygems, summarization

I'm trying to use the Summarize gem in Ruby, but when I do **gem install summarize**, i get:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing summarize:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/dev/Ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility   Version 1.50
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corp 1988-94. All rights reserved.

cl -nologo -I. -IC:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32 -IC:/dev/Ruby/lib
/ruby/1.8/i386-mswin32 -I. -MD -Zi -O2b2xg- -G6  -c -Tcarticle.c
cl : Command line warning D4029 : optimization is not available in the standard
edition compiler
cl : Command line warning D4002 : ignoring unknown option '-Og-'
article.c
article.c(21) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such
file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Gem files will remain installed in C:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/summarize-
1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/dev/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/summarize-1.0.3/ext/summari
ze/gem_make.out
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Microsoft C++ compiler. Install MinGW: it is a port of the POSIX toolset you'll find in *nixes (including GCC, the GNU compiler).

http://www.mingw.org/

If you used RubyInstaller to install Ruby, there's a nicely-packaged version of MinGW you're recommended to use:

http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/